# Android transparency and Shadows

Tags: android, transparency, shadow

I have a card view with a transparent background color and an elevation of 4dp.

It seems that there's no way to block the shadow from being visible inside the transparent card. I keep getting a weird outline which must be the shadow drawn underneath.

Is there any way (that works on API 21 and above) to only draw the shadow outside of my card so I can use transparent colors without artifacts?

**card view STYLE xml**

```
<style name="GridCard" parent="CardView">
        <item name="cardCornerRadius">4dp</item>
        <item name="cardElevation">4dp</item>
        <item name="cardUseCompatPadding">true</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">16dp</item>
        <item name="cardBackgroundColor">@color/white_70</item>
</style>
```

`white_70` is `#50FFFFFF`

**here's what it looks like (weird border caused by the shadow):**

[image: here's what it looks like. weird border caused by the shadow]

Comment: Can you provide images and xml code?

Comment: Just added them to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `cardUseCompatPadding` as `false` to remove inner `padding` and `shadow`.

**Try this style:**

```
<style name="GridCard" parent="CardView">
    <item name="cardCornerRadius">4dp</item>
    <item name="cardElevation">4dp</item>
    <item name="cardUseCompatPadding">false</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">16dp</item>
    <item name="cardBackgroundColor">@color/white_70</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Post your cardview xml and related resources and also post the style of "CardView"

Comment: I just found there was also a backgroundTint set in the cardView's xml. I took it out and now it works as you suggested!